# Guessing Game isdigit help python

Tags: python

I created a guessing game that only allows the user to type 4 numbers. My error is "'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'". I'm trying to make it so when the user types an alphabetical letter it displays an error message saying something like "Type only numbers" and lets the user guess again. Can someone give me suggestions?

Thank you!

Sorry for my English (Not my first language)

```
import random
n = random.randint(0, 9999)
guesses = 0
print()

while True: 

  guess = (input("Enter number from 0 to 9999"))
  guess = int(guess)

  if not guess.isdigit():
      print("Only numbers are allowed")

  else:
    guess = int(guess)
    guesses = guesses + 1

    if len(str(guess)) != 4:
      print (guesses, guess, "Invalid! 4 characters only")
      print()

    elif guess < n:
      print (guesses, guess, "too low")
      print()

    elif guess > n:
      print (guesses, guess, "too high")
      print()

    elif guess == n:
      break

print (guesses ,guess, "You guessed it!")
```

Comment: remove `guess = int(guess)` after `guess = (input("Enter number from 0 to 9999"))`

Answer (score 1):

`isdigit` can be invoked only for a string and not for an `int`

You have to check if the given string can be converted into an `int` by invoking `isdigit` and then convert into an `int`

```
if not guess.isdigit():
    print("Only numbers are allowed")

guess = int(guess)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python encourages the use of [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp), so you can write this code:

```
guess = input("Enter number from 0 to 9999")

try:
    guess = int(guess)
except ValueError:
    print("Only numbers are allowed")
    continue
```

When the conversion from the input string to an integer fails, the builtin converter will raise a `ValueError`. And when you catch one such error, you know it's not a valid integer and can take actions accordingly.